# Save the results of a join statement? SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm able to join three tables together, but I can't figure out a way to save the resulting table. The join statement I am using is:

```
SELECT * FROM
Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
INNER JOIN Table3
ON Table1.id = Table3.id
```

I've tried INSERT INTO, SELECT INTO, etc., and I am still unable to find a way to save the following query as a table. This must be possible, but I can't figure it out!

id is a shared identifier for all tables.

Comment: what problem are you facing using `SELECT INTO` or `INSERT INTO`?

Comment: Where do you want to "save" them to?

Comment: I simply want to save the results of this table as another table. Perhaps a Table4. I can't figure out a way to have a SELECT INTO statement that is also involves a JOIN.

Comment: Why don't you use views?

Comment: Assuming your `select` statement works, the syntax is `select * into table4...`.  Also you will need to alias the columns since you have multiple id columns for example, the new table cannot contain the same column names.

Comment: @TomJones as a permanent copy of that data at this point in time? As an always-current view of this data?

Comment: @TomJones What do you mean you can't figure out the way?, just do the same as if there was no `JOIN`: `SELECT some_columns INTO result_table FROM table1 INNER JOIN ....`

Comment: `SELECT INTO` is used to create a table and insert the data, `INSERT INTO` will insert data into a previously created table. Use the suggestion in @sgeddes comment.

Comment: @sgeddes I was using the multiple IDs as a means of joining the tables and keeping the data consistent. I don't want duplicate IDs to show up.

Comment: You should replace `*` with column list and provide aliases desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT Table1.*, 
    Table2.OtherColumn, 
    Table3.AnotherColumn,
    Table3.OneMoreColumn
    INTO TablesAsOf_20160215
    FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.id = Table2.id
    INNER JOIN Table3
    ON Table1.id = Table3.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you cannot create a new table with the same column names.  Since your tables share some of the same fields, you have to rename those when inserting by aliasing them.

Here's a quick example:

```
select t1.id as t1id, t2.id as t2id, t3.id as t3id into Table4
from Table1 t1
    join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    join Table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.id
```

This would create a new table, `Table4`, with 3 columns, `t1id`, `t2id` and `t3id`.  Add as many columns as you need at this point.

Comment: This is very close to what I am trying to do. All of the columns for Table 1-3 have completely different data - the only data that is the same is the ID column. I essentially want to merge all 3 tables together on that ID so I have 1 giant table with all varied columns and only 1 ID row.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can create a stored procedure or view. In that way you always get the results of your join statement without recreating it every time.

Answer (score 0):

First issue I would have is that you're using SELECT *

Use the column names, then as mentioned by sgeddes, be sure to rename each column, perhaps with a table prefix (t1id, t2id etc.)

However, be wary of the fact that the way you're joining tables together, the id has to exist in both places.

Run something like the code below to get an idea of how it works.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (id INT, val VARCHAR(50));
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (id INT, val VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, 'a');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (2, 'b');
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES (2, 'b');
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES (3, 'c');

SELECT t1.id AS t1id, t2.id AS t2id, t1.val AS t1val, t2.val AS t2val
FROM #Table1 t1 INNER JOIN #Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score -1):

You should save selected data temporarily by using procedure or function, then you will save into new table.

Comment: Can you give me an example or link of a function/procedure please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540794/stored-procedure-in-pl-sql-to-insert-new-record-in-table   Follow this link